# How can I run heroku container 24/7?

Tags: docker, heroku, ros

I have successfully uploaded my container to Heroku container and I am running ROS inside that container.

The issue is, I have to run heroku run bash --app=ros-app in order to get into the dyno bash and run some commands to start my application.

So the question is: is it possible to run my app inside the container without actually running a bash on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run commands inside a Docker container, can you edit your Dockerfile to use the [CMD instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)? This will allow for Docker to start your application by executing a command inside the container when the container is started.

Comment: So if I have entrypoint script, shall I just use CMD to run that script whenever I release the container and it will run without me getting inside the dyno container?